# Algorithm design: taking words, shifting letters and forming a sentence with them

Tags: algorithm

Within our organization, we were given some sort of assignment / mini competition where we have been given a list of words (brands of water). The goal is to switch the letters of these words around, and end up with a sentence. Because the list is not all too short (about 10 words, most not even very short ones) I figured I wanted to look into programming the solution for this problem.

I do have a technical background, but I am not a full blown programmer, let alone have enough insight to create an algorithm of this magnitude.

The biggest catch will be the matching of the words, as well as the grammar. I've found one list of words, but I do not believe this one contains different forms of the verbs. I will look into finding more of these, but I hope there is an alternative with some kind of existing grammar engine or API. **The catch: this needs to be done in DUTCH, not in English**.

The actual forming of the sentence (as in the order of the words) is of less importance. If the output is a list of "sentences" that disregard word order, I can filter those out that don't make any sense manually, and then swap words around in order to have it make sense.

It would be much appreciated if someone with the right skillset would be able to point me in the right direction, or help me out another way.

Get those braincells working :-)
Regards

Comment: Unless you can get hold of one of the awesome software featuring in CSI, I think you have to do this the traditional way. You are talking about throwing around ~75-125 characters and trying to find matches from a 240.000 word language (http://www.ikhebeenvraag.be/vraag/7996) and then from that figuring out which of the thousands of sentences you will be given is the correct one. But you would only have that problem if you have the hardware that could perform this task before the due date. But maybe this is just me being negative.

Answer (score 0):

There's an online anagram finder that will work with Dutch [here](http://wordsmith.org/anagram/advanced.html).  Their maximum permitted input length is 35 characters (server load dependent), but you could contact them and sweet-talk/bribe them into running the problem on a longer input set.

Comment: Much appreciated, I've sent them an email. Also trying out another tool I found, which is supposed to be able to do it but I can't get my head around it, documentation is terrible and terms used are even worse... it's like he invented his own kind of regexp

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this right, you seem to have two parts to your problem here.

First, you need to take all the words, try all possible permutations of the letters in every word and build a new list of words from it.

Second, you need to try all possible ways of creating valid phrases from the new list of words.

The first problem is quite do-able. I think even doing it without any optimization is still okay, thought it may take a bit to compute (keep in mind that even just a 7 letter word, for example, will have ~5000 possible permutations, though certainly the large majority of these would not result in valid words). You would need access to a copy of a dictionary (just the words, not the definitions) and you'd probably want to store this in a trie or at least a hashset for quick access, since you need to quickly check for every permutation if it's a valid word.

The second problem though is IMO not really a walk in the park. You will end up with a rather large list of words I think. Then:

- You need to check possible ways of arranging these words to compose a valid phrase. This is not an easy problem. Even for a relatively short phrase there will be many possible phrase structures (by that I mean arrangement of the possible syntactical functions).
- for everyone of these arrangements (think of them like ways to arrange boxes), there will be many ways to put your words in them. (e.g. every noun in there can be a subject). It's also not easy to figure out what function each word can have, you would need some natural language parsing library to help you figure this out.
- Finally you will end up with a LOT of possible phrases, most of which won't make any sense. How to check if they do make sense? That's not at all trivial :) And if you can't do that and have to manually go through all of them, I think that's quite a bit of work.

I am thinking that maybe there would be some way to "cheat" around these difficult issues with figuring out the semantic and maybe even generating the phrases and just use Google search to help you figure out phrases. As in, use their auto-fill and auto-correct functionality to determine if your phrase is valid. I could see some approaches going that way..

All in all, I think you have a problem that grows exponentially (all possible combination of letters -> all possible combinations of resulting words) and requires quite a bit of smart filtering to prune out all the invalid entries and keep it from getting too big. It's definitely something that can be done, but it does require quite a bit of work.

I'm curious to hear other thoughts on this though :)